# Routh Hurwitz Criterion for Stability

Tags: control-theory

What do the rows of the Routh table represent? What is the significance of writing the powers of 's' in the zeroth column?

Comment: For reference slides 47 until 53 ... http://engineering.nyu.edu/mechatronics/Control_Lab/Criag/Craig_RPI/2001/Controls_Intro_Stab_Perf_Modes.pdf

Comment: And this one (most interesting) https://my.ece.utah.edu/~bodson/ifs/routh.pdf

Comment: See also the example for computing the numbers of real roots https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem

Comment: the "most interesting" one is really good; thanks